# How to get domain name from user's input of e-mail adress and turn it to link to mailbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen numerous web-sites that suggests to proceed directly to mailbox. It detecs email domain and turns it to link.

Answer (score 1):

To get the domain from an email use `split`:

```js
const email = "person@example.com";
const [, domain] = email.split("@");
console.log(domain);
```

To add it to a button:

```js
const email = "person@example.com";
const [, domain] = email.split("@");
document.getElementById("button").setAttribute("href", `http://${domain}`);
```

```html
<a id="button">Link</a>
```

Comment: I wouldn't ask such a basic thing.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what you need? The answer above with the mailto: link does do exactly what yo appear to be asking

Comment: For example: I fill in email: username@emaildomain.com. After cliking sign up the button suggest to check mailbox. the url of button - emaildomain.com

Comment: Ohh, I see. I'll add that @CyrylRozumowski.

Comment: Edited @CyrylRozumowski, any better?

Comment: Thank You for the solution :)